# How to keep JPA Fetch child data when using CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, completable-future

Hi i trying to multithreading my function that execute queries with different condition, but i think JPA lost it's persistent bag while i am doing it, since the data won't show up and i got an error. I will start with my synchronous code first since it work, and i will show my async code that not work.

here is my Entity class :

TransSalesOrder class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "transSalesOrder")
private List<TransDeliveryOrder> transDeliveryOrder;
```

TransDeliveryOrder class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deliveryOrder", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<TransDeliveryOrderDetail> transDeliveryOrderDetail;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "transSalesOrderId")
private TransSalesOrder transSalesOrder;
```

and here is TransDeliveryOrderDetail class :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "delivery_order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private TransDeliveryOrder deliveryOrder;
```

Here is my synchronous way that work :
this is my function, that execute 3 others function :

```
public List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findUnAssignedSO() {
    List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> transSalesOrdersResponseNew = findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly();
    transSalesOrdersResponseNew.addAll(findPureUnAssignedSO());
    transSalesOrdersResponseNew.addAll(findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder());

    return transSalesOrdersResponseNew;
}
```

and here is 3 function that executed :

```
private List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly() {
    List<TransSalesOrder> transSalesOrders = iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findSOHaveLeftOverButDone();
    return buildTransSalesOrdersResponseNew(transSalesOrders);
}

private List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findPureUnAssignedSO() {
    return iSalesOrderMapper.entityToSOOnlyDto(iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findUnAssignedSalesOrder());
}

private List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder() {
    List<TransSalesOrder> transSalesOrders = iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder();

    return buildTransSalesOrdersBpsjOnlyResponseNew(transSalesOrders);
}
```

in this way is worked, but then i try to async my 3 method since 3 of my function can execute in async way, they don't have to wait each other to complete

here is my Asynchronous way using CompletableFuture :

```
public List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findUnAssignedSO() {
    List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> transSalesOrdersResponseNew = new ArrayList<>();

    findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly()
            .thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll )
            .thenCompose( v -> findPureUnAssignedSO() )
            .thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll )
            .thenCompose( v -> findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder() )
            .thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll )
            .join();

    return transSalesOrdersResponseNew;
}

private CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        List<TransSalesOrder> transSalesOrders = iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findSOHaveLeftOverButDone();
        return buildTransSalesOrdersResponseNew(transSalesOrders);
    });
}

private CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> findPureUnAssignedSO() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> iSalesOrderMapper.entityToSOOnlyDto(iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findUnAssignedSalesOrder()));
}

private CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        List<TransSalesOrder> transSalesOrders = iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder();

        return buildTransSalesOrdersBpsjOnlyResponseNew(transSalesOrders);
    });
}
```

when i run my findUnAssignedSO function, i got this error :

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
> a collection of role:
> com.bit.microservices.b2b.warehouse.entity.TransSalesOrder.transSalesOrderDetail,
> could not initialize proxy - no Session

when i debug it, i found the child data is not loaded, here is the option i try :

- i trying to keep the JPA attach using @Transactional, it's not working.
- i don't want change my fetchType in @OneToMany relation to EAGER, i read all around internet that will have performance issue later
- Using Set insted of List, this will cause performance issue too

i didn't show my repository since i use JpaRepository and QueryDSL, which is mixed, but i am open for any solution doesn't need to attached to QueryDSL. How can i fetch the data properly?

Comment: You should check that everything runs in the same thread. The session is not thread-safe and could have strange behaviours when used by different threads. Also, why do you want to use `CompletableFuture`? I don't think you will gain anything from it in this particular case.

Comment: Where exactly is the error coming from? You already know that the objects are detached from the context you are reading them from when you are accessing lazy (unfetched) relationships because you've closed the asynchronous threads/contexts used to read them, so I don't quite know what you are looking for. You must pre-fetch the data you need before the context closes, or run the fetches synchronously in the process that uses the data so the context can remain open. As for efficiency of fetching 1:M relationships 'eagerly' - that is a separate problem with many solutions.

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-fetchmode for fixing your collection mappings so that you can keep them lazy (or eager) and not have it join to the main table when fetching - you are currently causing N* queries already as your method goes through the returned data and touches lazy relationships. If you want to keep the model relationships lazy, just have your async methods touch them before returning, or use graphs/hints to force JPA to fetch them for you before the context closes and the data is returned. Key is knowing what you need before you need it.

Comment: @Davide ohh i want to execute 3 database query in separated thread, so they don't have to wait each other to finish, because each of the query will get thousand of record, i want to improve the performance using CompletableFuture, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Chris as i mention, i don't want to change the fetchType, since fetchMode will override fetchType, it will affect my other function performance

Comment: Performance is a tricky subject. It's hard to know if it will improve without benchmarks. That said, make sure that you are not sharing the same session among different threads or you might have problems.

Comment: FetchMode.SUBSELECT and other types work with fetch type lazy. You then only need to trigger the lazy relationships before your asynchronous process returns the data - This allows lazy relationships without N queries (or N* the data when joining a parent to many children relationship). You then only need to traverse the relationship before returning the objects. transSalesOrder.gettransDeliveryOrder.getdeliveryOrder().getSomething() in a loop on the results while in the context to ensure it is fetched before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch performance is a difficult topic and I totally understand that you don't want to change the fetch type or mode on entity level. Usually, this can be solved by using entity graphs for defining a graph of associations to fetch which are per-query. In your particular case, the problem is that the threads do not fetch all the state that is later needed. When you access that state later in a different thread, the proxy has no reference to a persistence context anymore (because it's bound to a transaction/thread) and fails with the LazyInitializationException you are seeing. You can solve this by using an entity graph so that no lazy loading happens, or by enabling the `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` property which will create a session on-demand for fetching the data, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(TransSalesOrder.class)
public interface TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    List<TransDeliveryOrderDto> transDeliveryOrder;

    @EntityView(TransDeliveryOrder.class)
    interface TransDeliveryOrderDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!